# Pandas replace empty cell with string from previous filled cell

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I want to replace empty cells in column A with previous string from column A.
I have Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
      A       B
1   Roses   Name1
2           Name2
3   Tulips  Name3
4           Name4
5   Cactus  Name5
6           Name6
```

I want to replace empty cells with previous value from the column and count how many people have certain type of plant.

The desired result should look like this:

```
      A       B
1   Roses   Name1
2   Roses   Name2
3   Tulips  Name3
4   Tulips  Name4
5   Cactus  Name5
6   Cactus  Name6
```

I tried replacing empty cells with nan using `df = df.astype(str)` and tried using `df.fillna()` however that didn't seem to work for me.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Use `df['A'] = df['A'].replace('', np.nan).ffill()`

Answer (score 1):

Replace the empty strings with NaN and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace('', float('nan')).ffill()
```

Or:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].mask(df['A'].str.fullmatch(' *')).ffill()
```

Output:

```
        A      B
1   Roses  Name1
2   Roses  Name2
3  Tulips  Name3
4  Tulips  Name4
5  Cactus  Name5
6  Cactus  Name6
```

If you just want to count, directly combine with `value_counts`:

```
df['A'].replace('', float('nan')).ffill().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Roses     2
Tulips    2
Cactus    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```